# Keeping Xv Overlay configuration throughout an X session

Tags: 10.10, xorg, video

After upgrading my Linux system from Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 10.10, I suceeded correcting most problems (all related to Intel 82865G Integrated Graphics Adapter support and compiz is still not working but that's another matter) but for one I only have a partial solution.

Whenever I play a video the colors are much too saturated. This is really a problem for tones of skins that appears reddish (everyone seems to be coming back from a ski vacation with deep sun burns). As this effect only occurs with videos, not with pictures, I finally figured out it was related to Video Overlays configuration and I can correct it typing:

```
xvattr -a XV_SATURATION -v 120
```

This change the default saturation value, which is 500 and much too high in my case, at eye sight the correct value seems to be between 100 and 150.

Now my problem is that I have to type the above command each time I run a video. If I type it before running the video it has no effect, if I close the video and open a new one, I have to type it again, etc. I tried to put it in Xsession and (logically) it has no effect either.

How could I do to get the correct setting whenever I run a video without typing the above command every time ?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards